# Search an Audio inside another Audio in C# or C++

Tags: c#, c++, pattern-matching, voice-recognition

Suppose there is a sample audio file that contains up to 10 simple words

> "One Two Three .... Ten"

and there is 1 second silence between each number in the audio file.

I want to check to see if the audio file contains keyword "Two" for example.
Please note that I have the keyword "Two" voice file and it's the same exact voice from the master voice file, but It may contain some noise.

Is there a way for me to search the voice "Two" inside that bigger audio file and find the occurrence time?

Comment: I'm not an expert in the area so take my initial impression as you will.. but pattern-matching isn't nearly as accurate as other machine-learning techniques. That said, I suppose you could do something like choose a length of time that is large enough for the largest sample (say.. 1.5 seconds if that's how long it took to say "three"), and convolve across your sample comparing a correlation of the fourier-domain of your source and the fourier-domain of that 1.5 sec slice of your master file and keep track of when the correlation was the highest.

Comment: Audio and simple do not go together.

Answer (score 2):

Since there's no provided code, i'll just give you the idea how to proceed, hope it'll help.

First you have to split your file to 10 different audio files according to silence (I'm sure there are libraries that will help you do that).

Then you can send the file to google voice recognition api, and get a string as a result, which will contain the string according to the voice in the file.

EDIT: Please refer to:
https://googlespeechtotext.codeplex.com/

[How to use google speech recognition api in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148373/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-c)

Comment: I checked there is no "google voice recognition api", or I can't find it!

Comment: It seems that google somehow removed it's api. I can't find it in Api Console to enable it on my google account.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just work out to convert both the audio samples into some bits or signal formats and check if they both have a some common strings.

Some of the links you should check before going any further just to work out with audio in .Net:

> http://crsouza.com/2009/08/converting-audio-bit-depths-in-c/
>   https://cscore.codeplex.com/
>   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/501521/How-to-convert-between-most-audio-formats-in-NET

Let me know if you can work this out.