# Google Cloud Speech API C#

Tags: api, speech, google-cloud-speech

I have used AT&T Watson for performing Voice-to-Text transcriptions for a couple of years now.  It has been reliable and "ok" as a service but they are discontinuing the service in October.

I know MS Exchange can transcribe voicemails... I assume it is implemented via Microsoft.Speech?  But I have read many posts that say Microsoft.Speech doesn't support dictation... on the other hand I've seen SAPI COM examples (foundation for Microsoft.Speech) that do support dictation.

System.Speech is a desktop solution that requires training, so that is not an option when transcribing voicemails.

I tried the Bing transcription service yesterday and it was absolute garbage compared to AT&T and Nuance wants an absolute fortune for their service, so that leaves me with...

Google Cloud Speech API, but for the life of me I can not find C# .Net sample code for THIS API after looking for 2 days.

Does anyone have c# sample code for Google Cloud Speech API.... By the way, this is a very new service, so examples from last year don't work for the current API.

Comment: This might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148373/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-c?rq=1

Comment: I'm just looking for help accessing the Google Speech API using c#.  I was trying to outline what I've already tried so people wouldn't waste time offering solutions that I've already tried.