# Google Speech Api in C# code

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

I am developing application in C# for speech recognition. I want to use google speech api for that purpose. I am developing application for this scenario
for Example:
I: I need your help my Computer?
Application: What type of help you required for me.

I generate key from Google cloud platform--> API ID manager--> credential.
I take code from here [How to use google speech recognition api in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25148373/how-to-use-google-speech-recognition-api-in-c)

Help me out how to solve this problem?

Comment: I think your question and problem is not clear.

Comment: where is the confusion?

Comment: You did not asked nothing at all.

Comment: i want to develop speech recognitionWPF C#(application) using google speech API? Can you tell me how to use google speech api in WPF application?

Comment: I mean you have to share your way that you tried nevermind I found an example that may help: [wpf-easy-text-to-speech-speech](http://dream-coder.blogspot.com.tr/2013/11/wpf-easy-text-to-speech-speech.html)

Comment: Yes i am asking for solution. Can you tell me please what is happening above link please. Is that project using google speech api?

Comment: google has some good introductory material here: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/getting-started and here: https://cloud.google.com/speech/docs/samples